# Getting list of events from a Facebook Page

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

So I have a friend who is a musician and has a page set up. He has asked me if there is a way of getting all the events on his Facebook Page via the Graph API and then putting them onto his website. I said I'd look into if this is even possible given that the API is now at version 2 and the PHP SDK has been bumped up to version 4.

Does anyone know how I'd do this? I already know how to make 'GET' request using the new PHP SDK, however I don't seem to be able to get the necessary fields.

Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's given on developers.facebook.com

```
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/{page-id}/events'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```

More at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/events

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Yeah it does although I'm only getting the first two events and there are a lot more on his page, the paging part doesn't seem to be working properly

Comment: Try adding  `?limit=50` to the call.

Comment: Yeah tried that and it doesn't seem to do anything, still only getting two events and have no idea why. I've tried limit=25 and limite=50 both of which didn't work, yet there are definitely more events as if I run a foreach loop again using the 'after' paging, I get the rest of the events :-/